# Create your own functor,C++

Tags: c++, transform, std, functor, clamp

I want to create a functor like `std::plus<>()` but also add `std::clamp` functionality to it.
Let's say it is a function `plus_clamp<>(T MIN = numeric_limits<T>::min(), T MAX = ...max())`
I started to look what implementation does `std::plus<>()` have, and tried to repeat it.

So I wrote something like this.

```
struct plus_clamp {
    template<typename T = void>
    constexpr T operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, T MIN = nl::min(),T MAX = nl::max()) {
        T result = std::plus<>();
        result = std::clamp(result, MIN,MAX);
        return result;
    }
};
```

But when I try to use that function with `std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),result.begin(), plus_clamp<>())`

I get compiler error
`error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`
`error: expected expression(at template parameter arg)`
`error: expected expression(at function arguments)`

I know that I am doing that wrong as I need to pass the template argument and the function arguments explicitly, but then this raises the question *how is `std::plus<>()` implemented so it skips the template and function arguments?*

Comment: `plus_clamp` itself is not a template. Remove the `<>`: `std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),result.begin(), plus_clamp())`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: its `operator()` is a template, but the template parameters can be deduced from the paramters

Comment: thanks, but now it complains ```error: no viable conversion from 'std::plus<>' to 'int'
            T result = std::plus<>();```

Comment: well no sorry, retracted close vote. You know that it is wrong already, but your interpretation is also wrong ;) and deserves an explanation

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: so how can I interpret that right? :D that was the part of the question))

Comment: You need to pass `lhs` and `rhs` to `std::plus<>()`

Comment: @NathanOliver I did it ```T result = std::plus<>(lhs,rhs);``` but now it says ```error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::plus<>'
            T result = std::plus<>(lhs,rhs);```

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried to remove ```<>``` but then it says no conversion from void to int

Comment: You need `std::plus<>{}(lhs,rhs);` so that you create an object of `std::plus` and then use it's `operator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code.

1. There is no way to pass the clamp values into the operator (if using `std::transform`), you need to pass them as constructor parameters to `plus_clamp`. This then means that `plus_clamp` needs to be a template rather than the operator.
2. Assuming `nl` is `std::numeric_limits` it is a template so needs the template type passed to it: `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`
3. `std::plus<>()` just constructing the type and not calling its operator. It should be `std::plus<>{}(lhs, rhs)`
4. When calling `std::transform` you pass `plus_clamp<>()`, in your original code `plus_clamp` isn't a template so you just need `plus_clamp()`.

A fully working example would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>

template<typename T = void>
struct plus_clamp {
    constexpr plus_clamp(T MIN = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),T MAX = std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
    : MIN(MIN), MAX(MAX)
    {
    }

    constexpr T operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
        T result = std::plus<>{}(lhs, rhs);
        result = std::clamp(result, MIN,MAX);
        return result;
    }

    T MIN;
    T MAX;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a,b, result;
    std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),result.begin(), plus_clamp<int>(10, 100));
}
```

If you are using c++17 you can use class template argument deduction and just use `plus_clamp(10, 100)`.

Comment: actually it seems I cannot have syntax like ```std::plus<>()```

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan why not? Here `std::plus<>{}(lhs, rhs);` is the same as `std::plus<>()(lhs, rhs);`

Comment: yep, I just used braces to disambiguate between creating the functor and calling it

Comment: because when I skip the template for ```plus_clamp<>``` it cannot have constructor with ```constexpr plus_clamp(void MIN = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),... ```

Comment: if you're using c++17 you can just omit the template arguments (assuming your clam values are the same type as your vector elements)

Answer (score 1):

Your `plus_clamp` is not a template. Hence you need to remove the `<>`:

```
std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),result.begin(), plus_clamp())
                                                                  // ^
```

[`std::plus<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) on the other hand is a template. It has an `operator()`:

```
constexpr T operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

You can either explitly select the type to add via:

```
T result = std::plus<T>()(lhs,rhs);
                   //^  T == int in your example
                      //^ create instance 
                        //^ call its operator()
```

or you use the default `std::plus<>` which is `std::plus<void>`. It has a `operator()` that deduces the type from its parameters:

```
T result = std::plus<>()(lhs,rhs);
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd54nE)